# Habilitar input ao clicar no botão dentro da mesma linha de uma tabela

Tags: jquery

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na linha da tabela acima tenho dois inputs desabilitados nas colunas `vlcontrato` e `valor`. Gostaria que ao clicar no botão `alterar` esses dois inputs fossem habilitados para que eu possa fazer a edição dos mesmos.

Uma vez que estão na mesma linha tentei usar o o método siblings porem só tive sucesso se o botão `alterar` estivesse dentro da mesma `td` que o input, porem o botão tem que ficar num `td` independente como na imagem acima!

Como devo proceder para chegar a essa operação?!

```
$('tr td .btn_alt').click(function(){   
    $(this).siblings('input[name=vlcontrato]').attr('readonly', false);
    $(this).siblings('input[name=vlcontrato]').focus(); 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Procura o elemento hierárquico que é comum aos elementos que procuras. É provavelmente a `<tr>`.

Assim podes usar o [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) para subir no DOM e encontrar esse "pai", o `<tr>` mais próximo, e daí voltar a descer no DOM com [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) para encontrareso elemento que procuras:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="vlcontrato"]').attr('readonly', false);
```

Se queres habilitar os dois inputs, então podes simplificar e usar:

```
$('tr td .btn_alt').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input').attr('readonly', false);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DuVyB/

---

#### Documentação jQuery:

[**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> Sobe no DOM e verifica a cada elemento o selector indicado, incluíndo o próprio.

[**.find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Retorna os descendentes the cada elemento que passam no filtro do seletor.